# how to custom fontsize and style inside buildmenu item flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

```
  buildMenuItem(
    text: 'Home',
    icon: Icons.home,
    onClicked: () => main(),
  ),
```

I want to add font-size inside buildmenuitem but still error please help me thank you

Comment: What is the error you're having?

Comment: red underline sir , i am newbie in flutter please help me

Comment: style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold), i have  try to adding this code inside buildmenuitem but error

Comment: Can you include the full widget code? And maybe add a comment on the line with the red underline?